# UINavigationBar moves with modal UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a modally presented `UITableView` that I needed to add a navigation bar to in Interface Builder (for saving and canceling). Now when I scroll, the navigation bar moves with the table view. Is there any way to lock it in place at the top?

Comment: You just used the "cocoa-touch" tag instead of the "xcode" tag which is - finally - appropriate. You rock! +1.

Comment: It is because you are adding the navigation bar into the tableview not in the view itself, so that it makes the navigation bar to be the headerView in the tableview. So need to remove the navigation bar and place it again on the top of the main view, and then place the table view such that it remains as you have expected.

Comment: As @insane-36 says. The tableView must be embedded in the navigation controller. You seem to do it the opposite.

Comment: I am using Storyboards so I did edit > embed in navigation controller. It crashed when I ran it and threw this exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:] (It is probably important to note that this a Core Data heavy app.)

Comment: Also, the main part of the app is embedded in a navigation controller. I added a modal segue from one of the views in the navigation controller to this table view.